# Show that there is a curve $c : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^P$ exists with $f(c(t)) = t \forall t\in I$

Tags: general-topology, partial-derivative

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^P \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be partially differentiable and the gradient be continuous for $a \in \text{Dom}({f})$ with $\text{grad}{f(a)} \ne 0$. Show that there is a curve $c : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^P$  with the interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ exists with $\forall t\in I,f(c(t)) = t$. I think I have to do something with the inverse but I am not sure.

Comment: What is $I$? Is it an arbitrary interval?

Comment: I suppose that $I$ is some interval that might depend on $f$.

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: However in my question it isn't specified so I just guess this from the function.

Comment: Some people uses $I$ only for the unit interval $[0,1]$. Whether or not $I$ means $[0,1]$ depends on where you find this question. But if $I=[0,1]$, then this cannot be true by the example $p=2$, $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1$. Are you sure that we want $f(c(t))=t$ and not $f(c(t))=0$?

Comment: yes, however the question where i got this from doesn't specify anything about $I$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2325401/219176

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\grad{\operatorname{grad}}
$
Since $\grad f$ is continuous and $\grad f(a) \neq 0$ there's some neighborhood $U \subseteq \mathbb R^P$ of $a$ on which $\grad f \neq 0.$

Let $\gamma \subset U$ be a [flow curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field#Flow_curves) of $\grad f$ through $a.$ Since $\grad f \neq 0$ along $\gamma,$ by [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) $f|\gamma$ is invertible, i.e. there exists a $c : f(\gamma) \to \gamma$ with $f(c(t)) = t.$ Here $f(\gamma) = \{ f(p) \mid p\in\gamma \}.$

Comment: I have only had this theorem for $I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with Interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$, could you show me how I can use this for more dimensions?

Comment: Is "this theorem" referring to the Inverse Function Theorem?

Comment: Yes it is, could have been a bit more clear.

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem ?

Comment: I have but especially the proof of multiple dimensions for the inverse function theorem is what I am interested in.

Comment: You can find several proofs via Google: https://www.google.se/search?q=inverse+function+theorem+proof